# Spending a night in Minsk and continuing my journey using my Fan ID

Tags: visas, belarus

I recently got to know that Russia and Belarus have an agreement and Fan ID can be used to transit through Belarus. I want to travel to Belarus after the final on 16 July (flight), spend a night in Minsk and leave for Egypt from Minsk. I'm not really sure if this trip can be carried out if I only have a Fan ID and no Belarus visa.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, you can.

According to [official claim](http://mvd.gov.by/en/main.aspx?guid=18391) of Belarusian MIA, it can be done till 25th of July:

> During the period that starts 10 days before the date of the first match and ends 10 days after the date of the last match (from 00:00 hours on June 4, 2018 **to 23:59 hours on July 25, 2018**), foreign spectators should leave the Republic of Belarus and the Russian Federation without visa processing.

So your night stay on 16th perfectly fits this time slot.